# Certificate Authentication and Message Security without private key in the certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with the certificates in WCF (client).

I have received three certificates:

- SSL certificate of the remote server
- client certificate (for the user authentication)
- root certificate

*Note: no certificate has a private key*

---

In WCF there is the possibility to use the certificate authentication. Here is my sample:

```
var sslBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
sslBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
sslBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;

var certificate= new X509Certificate2(_certificatesFullPath, _certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
var userCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_userCertificate, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

var identity = new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(userCertificate);
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(_endPointURI), identity);

using (Test.SdIRiceviNotificaClient client = new Test.SdIRiceviNotificaClient( sslBinding, endPoint))
{
        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;


        client.Open();

        var result = await client.NotificaEsitoAsync(new Test.NotificaEsitoRequest(idSdI.ToString(), fileName, XmlUtils.GetXmlBytes(new NotificaEsitoCommittente())));

        client.Close();
}
```

My problem is now that I receive this exception:

> The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate.

*I know that no certificate has a private key and I can not ask for other certificates.*

---

The only info that I have: all certificates should be used in a p12 container.
I have just the problem to create a p12 file (without a private key => ok there is the possibility with the "-nokeys" argument).

I have done this:

```
openssl x509 -in CAEntratetest.cer -outform PEM -out CAEntratetest.pem
openssl x509 -in SDI-xxxxxxxxxxx.cer -inform DER -out SDI-xxxxxxxxxxx.pem -outform PEM
openssl x509 -in testservizi.fatturapa.it.cer -inform DER -out testservizi.fatturapa.it.pem -outform PEM

cat CAEntratetest.pem SDI-xxxxxxxxxxx.pem testservizi.fatturapa.it.pem > sum.pem
```

To create a p12 file I need a private key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in sum.pem -inkey private.key -out output.p12
```

If I create a new key => it doesn't work (no certificate matches private key)

Is it possible to use certificates without a private key?

Comment: If it is about mutual authentication, maybe could you change your Question Title in order to show this and get more attention than talking about FatturaPA

Comment: Thanks, is correct. Have not thought about it. A detailed documentation of this service does not exist (is a service of the state for eBills).

Comment: Please turn back the time a little bit to ask yourself what you did before receiving the certificates. You cannot receive such without preparing certificate requests, in which process you already generated the private key. You just simply forgot where you left the key, and probably you need to do the whole thing once again.

Comment: @LexLi I have not created the certificates. I received the certificates from the "state" without a private key. This web service is an existing service and I should "only" connect me to this service.

Comment: @Elro that's impossible. You will need to reach out to who manages the service to ask how to locate the private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use a certificate for authentication without the private key.

The security of an [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) based authentication mechanism relies on public-key cryptography, where both public and private keys are generated. Only the private part should remain secret.

What you have is the public key. Signing something with your *private* key is what proves you 'own' the public key, and how you are authenticated.

Also note: you cannot simply generate a new private key for a public key. The keys are a pair.